# Naming collision with built in functions?

Tags: c++

I am getting an error while trying to build my C++ project.

I am trying to build a cross platform project involving sockets.  On Windows I need to call `closesocket` when a socket is closed, and on linux I just call close.

So, to make a cross-platform solution, I defined the following in my base class:

```
#define closesocket close
```

In my class code, I then have:

```
class TCPClient {
    void TCPClient::close()
    {
        closesocket(m_socket);
    }
}
```

However, I now get the following error when I try to build:

```
projects/cpp_sockets/src/project/tcp_client.cpp: In member function ‘void TCPClient::close()’:                                                                                                                        
/home/optonox/Documents/projects/cpp_sockets/src/project/tcp_client.cpp:44:22: error: no matching function for call to                                                                                                                        
 ‘TCPClient::close(SOCKET&)’                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  closesocket(m_socket);  


                  ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                    /home/optonox/Documents/projects/cpp_sockets/src/project/tcp_client.cpp:42:6: note: candidate: void TCPClient::close()                                                                                                                        
 void TCPClient::close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      ^~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
/home/optonox/Documents/projects/cpp_sockets/src/project/tcp_client.cpp:42:6: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1                                                                                                                        
 provided                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
src/project/CMakeFiles/cpp_sockets.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target 'src/project/CMakeFiles/cpp_sockets.dir/tcp_c
```

I would guess what is happening is that `closesocket` is `typedef`d as `close` so it tries to call the `TCPclient` member function?

A. Is that what is happening?
and 
B. How would I prevent this?

The project compiles fine if I comment out that call to `closesocket`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have *two* problems.

The first is how the preprocessor works, it replaces macro invocations before the actual C++ parser sees the code. That means with

```
#define closesocket close
```

and

```
void TCPClient::close()
{
    closesocket(m_socket);
}
```

what the C++ parser sees is

```
void TCPClient::close()
{
    close(m_socket);
}
```

That is, an attempt to call `TCPClient::close` *recursively* but passing an argument the function doesn't take.

The solution to this first problem is to avoid using macros as much as possible, and instead [*conditional compilation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation) in the `TCPClient::close` function directly.

The second problem is about scoping and is the reason for the apparently recursive call. You need to tell the compiler that you want to use the global `close` function, which is done using the scope-operator `::` as in

```
::close(m_socket);
```

Comment: I would have defined a wrapper function instead of using a `#define` macro: `int closesocket(int fd) { return ::close(fd); }`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that would not address the platform differences that the macro did.

Comment: @Startec actually, it would have, and in a type-safer way than the macro

Comment: How? Wouldn't `closesocket` overwrite the built-in windows function and the call to `return ::close` in the body of this function still seems like it would fail to call the windows function `closesocket`?